# rsyslogd - cannot create '/dev/log': permission denied as non-root user in Kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, rsyslog

I am trying to cutover a pod/container to a non-root user - rsyslogd runs as a process in this container.

I am intending to use supercronic as the cron-like process in my container and I am trying to set up logging from rsyslog.

When running `kubectl logs` on the container I can see the following error:

`rsyslogd: cannot create '/dev/log': Permission denied`

I have tried starting the rsyslogd process with `-i /tmp/rsyslogd.pid` but the error message still appears - is this due to running the container as non-root? Or some other config issue?